# Serializing a double property as string

Tags: java, json, jackson

Which @JsonXyz annotation do I have to use when I have a bean to be jsonified but serializing a double proeprty as string.

An example:
I have a bean:

```
public MyBean {
    private double myDouble;
    //getter and setter
}
```

And I wan tto have a JSON like:

```
{'myDouble':'100.0'}
```

instead of:

```
{'myDouble':100.0}
```

So, the value 100.0 shall be in quotes.

Comment: Are you using Jackson for json handling?

Comment: I am using:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
in the POJO. I hope not to have to use ObjectMapper or so. I hope the a simple annotation could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jackson you can use [`@JsonSerialize`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) and [`ToStringSerializer`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializer.html) :

```
public MyBean {
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private double myDouble;
    //getter and setter
    //constructors
}
```

The code to test it (Jackson version `2.9.8`) :

```
MyBean myBean = new MyBean(20.3);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myBean);

System.out.println(json);
```

The output is :

```
{"myDouble":"20.3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) with [`ToStringSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializer.html):

```java
@Data
public class MyBean {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    private double myDouble;
}
```

Or use [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) with [`JsonFormat.Shape.STRING`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html#STRING):

```java
@Data
public class MyBean {

    @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING)
    private double myDouble;
}
```

Both approaches produce the same result.

---

If you intend to use these annotations in multiple places, you may consider [`@JacksonAnnotationsInside`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.html) which allows you to create a custom annotation which contains one or more Jackson annotations:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
public @interface JsonString {

}
```

```java
@Data
public class MyBean {

    @JsonString
    private double myDouble;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change getter to return value as string instead of double

```
return String.valueof(variable)
```

And setter should be get the value as string parameter and set your double value with `Double.parseDouble(variable)`

```
Double myDouble;

public String getMyDouble() {
    return String.valueof(myDouble);
}

public void setMyDouble(String str) {
    myDouble = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Comment: See my comment for @Kushil Dodhia.